# Saving to Android Internal Storage

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream, internal-storage

At the moment i'm trying to save a response to the internal storage in the phone. Everything works fine up until i try and retrieve the data again. When i log out the retrieved data it only logs out one small section of the response and the rest isn't there. Ive tried deleting the file and calling it again just incase it was using an old one.

**Saving Code**

```
try {
     String response = apiResponse.getRawResponse();
     Log.e("Response", response);

     FileOutputStream userInfo = openFileOutput("personal_profile", MODE_PRIVATE);
     userInfo.write(response.getBytes());
     userInfo.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
```

**Retrieving Code**

```
 String response = "";

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = getActivity().openFileInput("personal_profile");
        DataInputStream isr = new DataInputStream(fis);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        line = response;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e("Saved File", response);
```

Any kind of suggestions would be great!

Comment: I think it requires WRITE permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**REASON**

The problem was that the **line variable is assigned again in every iteration**

Try this:

```
 String response = "";

try {
    FileInputStream fis = getActivity().openFileInput("personal_profile");
    DataInputStream isr = new DataInputStream(fis);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    line = response;

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**CHANGE LAST LINE**

```
Log.e("Saved File", sb.toString());
```

Comment: Correct! Could you possibly tell me what the problem was?

Answer (score 1):

Have you got this in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also, this link has everything you need to know about reading and writing files:

http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html

---

***Code***::

```
  String response = "";

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = getActivity().openFileInput("personal_profile");
        DataInputStream isr = new DataInputStream(fis);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        line = response;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e("Saved File", sb.toString());
```

Comment: You are also correct. I should have been logging out the string builder. Thanks for putting in the time to comment!